# "Keep informed" versus "stay informed"

Tags: word-choice, verbs

I saw "Keep Informed!" written under the social profiles of [a Firefox extension](http://update.downloadhelper.net/index.html?ts=1357844507) in its release notes.

I think, the writer wants to say "keep abreast of all the developments, bug fixes and new features". But is "keep informed" correct? Shouldn't it be "Stay informed"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both would be understood.

I would have said "stay informed" would be the more common, but [Google Books Ngram Viewer](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Keep+Informed%2CStay+Informed&year_start=1900&year_end=2010&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) suggests that it's more recent and was less common before becoming very common very recently.